Solving Error: TLS initialization failed on PySide2
When i use QNetworkAccessManager  and QNetworkRequest  it gives Error: TLS initialization failed .
I researched on internet and learned that i must install OpenSSL. Then i install OpenSSL3.3.1 and add. After adding it to the PATH, I placed the libcrypto and libssl DLL files in the Python/dlls and project directories. Then i restart my computer but result doesn't change.
So what should i do for solving this issue.

Please improve your question and add more details about your environment (OS, Qt and Python version), how you installed OpenSSL, how you added it to the PATH and where you actually copied which files. Note that before Qt 5.15.1 OpenSSL 3 wasn't supported.

I updated to PySide6 and it fixed thanks.
